# Python threading not running 2 processes at once

Tags: multithreading, python-3.7

I have 2 functions that both have a while True loop in them and when I try running both at them at once, only the first one runs.

I have tried doing this with threading.Thread(target=hello()).start() as well as with multiprocessing.Process(target=hello()).start() and none worked.

```
import threading
def hello():
    while True:
        print("hello")

def world():
     while True:
         print("world")

threading.Thread(target=hello()).start()
threading.Thread(target=world()).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of CPython's [Global Interpreter Lock](https://realpython.com/python-gil/) . When you run your first thread, the second one is blocked and won't start running until the first is finished. In your case, the first thread has an infinite loop inside, so the second one is never awoken

What I'd suggest you is to use [asyncio](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/). It'll do the right work for you:

```
# python3.7+
import asyncio


async def hello():
    while True:
        print("Hello")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def world():
    while True:
        print("World")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(hello(), world())


asyncio.run(main())
```

Note **asyncio.sleep(1)** call in each coroutine. It's done to pass the control to the event loop and let another coroutine to be executed.